# How to read a accessToken file that's located in a App_Data folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, .net-core

I have this Azure function which has code to upload a video to my YouTube channel whenever there is a video file in the "video" container. The code I am using is from the YouTube API sample code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert .

I have taken this code, and I placed it inside an Azure function (code below). When I compile and run the function locally, it runs fine and I am able to upload a video using Azure Storage Explorer and I see the videos get uploaded in my YouTube channel fine.

However, when I publish the function to Azure portal and run the function, the function just times out because it is expecting a UI as it requires user interaction for sign-in. As you may know, Azure function is not an interactive process.

So to get over that, I want to use the same access token file, that was created when I ran my code locally the first time, and upload the function with that token file again to Azure, to avoid for user authentication prompt. But the access token file is in my `%appdata%` folder, so I want to move that file to the same directory as my code and then read that file to get the access token.

I have a file that is in my

```
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user
```

I want to move the `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user` (which contains my access token) file into the same directory as my code and read that file.

**Question**: how do I change the code so that it will *read* the file from the same directory as my code and not from `%appdata%`?

I think I should able to use this block of code(https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) to do that, but I am not sure how it fits the rest of my existing function:

Block of code from website:

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{   
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
         GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
         new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
         "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
         CancellationToken.None,
         new FileDataStore("credfolder", true)).Result;
}
```

Here is my full existing function:

```
    using System
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
    using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace AzureFunctionToUploadToYoutube
    {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("Function1")]

            public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Function triggered by blob." + name);
                UserCredential credential;
                log.LogInformation("Getting client secrets.");

                using (var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                    );
                }

                log.LogInformation("Done getting secrets.");
                log.LogInformation("Creating youtube service");

                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
                });

                log.LogInformation("Done creating service.");
                var video = new Video();
                video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
                video.Snippet.Title = name;
                video.Snippet.Description = "Seattle Channel";
                video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
                video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
                video.Status = new VideoStatus();
                video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
                var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");

                log.LogInformation("Trying to upload video");

                try
                {
                    await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
                    log.LogInformation("Done uploading video.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Error uploading video: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add clarification on where your problem lies here. Is the problem reading the file, or applying `credential` to `YouTubeService`? Does `HttpClientInitializer = credential` not work? Is there an error, etc?

Comment: @John The problem I am having is that, when I publish the function to Azure, it timeouts because it is waiting for the user to authenticate themselves. As you know Azure function is not an interactive process.  So to get over that, I am going to use the same access token file and upload the function again to avoid user authentication. But the access token file is in my %appdata% folder, hence I want to move that file in the same directory as my code and read that file to get the access token.

Comment: @John the problem/question is how do i read the "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-use" file, once it is in the same directory as my function(code).

Comment: I see. You should edit all that info into your question. I don't have an answer but hopefully it'll help someone else answer you :-)

Comment: @John sure, thanks

Comment: does the Auth file is static or is it being created every time for eache request?

Comment: @kleinohad the "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" gets created when I run the code the first time. So no, it is not created every time. Which is why I am asking how can I read that "TokenResponse-use" file in my code so that I can use that when I publish my function to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Azure Blob to save the file and each time the function is running check if the file exist on the blob.
If the file doesn't exist on the blob create it.
You can read about saving file to blob from function here:
https://www.cyotek.com/blog/upload-data-to-blob-storage-with-azure-functions

Comment: No, this does not answer my question. I am asking how to read the token file in code.

Comment: looks like GoogleClientSecrets.Load expects  steam, mybe you can copy the Auth file to azure blob and read at as stream from there